# JQuery date picker substring to get month in particular format

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker, substring

I'm implementing a date picker. I want the date to be the following format

`MM-DD-YY` using `myDate.getFullYear().substring(0,2)`

How come substring is not working here?

```
 $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
            var myDate = new Date();
            var prettyDate =(myDate.getMonth()+1) + '-' + myDate.getDate() + '-' + myDate.getFullYear().substring(0,2);
            $("#datepicker").val(prettyDate);
          });
```

Comment: What error are you getting here? Could you describe what output you are seeing in more detail?

Comment: myDate.getFullYear() returns an integer, which has no substring method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date.getFullYear()` returns an integer, which has no substring method.  You'll want to call `.toString()` on it first.

But then, that will give you the century.  Eg, [for today's date, you would get `"20"`](http://jsfiddle.net/7xY5j/).  You want [`.toString().substring(2,4)`](http://jsfiddle.net/7xY5j/1/).